# How to use JWT JSON Web Tokens in C# AspNetCore Websites?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I am trying to pull together a website that uses JWTs for login.  My problem is that I do not understand how a website should use the JWTs.

The idea is to split my monolithic architecture into:

- An IdentityServer for authentication and issuing JWTs.
- An ApplicationServer API that has endpoints protected by JWT based roles.
- Front-end Apps and Websites that request JWTs from the IdentityServer, and use them to access data on the ApplicationServer.

This will allow me to use one IdentityServer for many projects, and possibly farm front end development out to 3rd parties, and allow me to concentrate on the application API details.

I have the IdentityServer built.  It can take a username/password, validate, and issue an access token and a refresh token.  Super.
The access token is short-lived and non-secure, and intended to be refreshed periodically.  The intention is to store this on the client side, either app or web page.
The refresh token is longer-lived, and intended to be stored securely.  On a website, this would be stored server-side, and in an app, stored in secure storage for the 'session' duration.

I have a front end website shell set up with some test actions.  The user must be authenticated to access them, where being authenticated means having a valid access token.

- When the user accesses an action initially, they have no token.
- The front-end webserver should redirect them to a login page, and request credentials (username and password).
- The webserver forwards credentials to IdentityServer, which should return access and refresh tokens to the webserver if the credentials are valid.
- The webserver would cache the refresh token and send the access token back to the webpage.
- The client-side webpage would then cache the access token and send that with each further page request.
- The webserver would decode the access token, possibly refresh it if necessary, and send back the pages with the updated access token.
- The conversation (session) ends when a request comes in with a stale access token and enough time has elapsed for the refresh token to expire, and the user is re-directed to the login page.

I am a little lost as to how to return the access token to the webpage.

Also, I do not understand how the web page could either automatically attach a token with each request if it has one, or how a web page could respond to a 401 challenge if it does not.

Is a cookie the only way to attach data to an HTTP conversation, and persist it on the client side during navigation?

Are JWTs purely for SinglePageApps (SPAs) where a page is initially served, and then all subsequent data is handled by Ajax (where I can set the header no problem)?

Alternatively, is it possible to write the webpages such that they always populate the Authorization header with the access token, if it exists?

I realise that I may have thought myself into a knot, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that your token, should be stored in the web request header.  With it being on every request, it allows the challenge. On every call, to validate access.  Rather than a cookie, though it is an option.

Comment: Yep, what I do not understand is how to get each request from the client side to include the Authorization header.

Comment: Why can't you manually add the header with authorization, bearer, and the provided token value on each request?  `request.Headers.Add("authorization", $"bearer={token}");`. Something along those lines?

Comment: Is this in JavaScript on the client side?  How does the client side know to populate this header?  Apologies if I am being stupid.  I totally get how this works if an app is configuring an Http request, or if the request is Ajax, but if the user types in a URL or navigates to another page via a link, how does the request include the header?  I am guessing that only cookies will do this, but I was thinking that JWTs would replace cookies.

Comment: That was a C# style approach, but from Ajax or Axios, you could manipulate the header: `$.ajax({ headers: {'authorization', 'bearer=' + token}});`. Would be along those lines.

Comment: Yes, this I understand, Ajax or an App, no problem.  How does this happen with AspNetCore controllers/actions and views etc?  Does the page have to have JavaScript to respond to a 401 challenge?

Comment: Identity should allow you to utilize `[Authorize(role="Administrator")]` on your Controller.  Which expects each request to be validated.

Comment: Yes, I get that, and I have this working. I have actions with Authorize attributes, and I can make a manual Postman request, strap in the "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" header, and I can access the protected endpoints.  What I do not know is how to make pages that will populate this header, as the user will not be using Postman, they will be browsing my site.  Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: Are you expecting to attach the JWT token header during normal page navigation from page to page outside the context of a SPA? Or are you making raw AJAX calls using vanilla JS or jQuery, etc? A combination of both?

Comment: Both. My current sits is a main SPA app page with various support pages around it.  This uses cookies.  Is it possible to use JWTs instead of cookies, or do I have to wrap the JWT inside a cookie to transfer with navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a read up on Auth0's documentation for **Resource Owners Password Grant** https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/password

I would keep the refresh token and the access token together on the client.

My approach would be.

Client knows it doesnt have an access token -> shows login button.
Login button clicked -> redirect to authentication server with login page.  It includes a state/code and a callback url.
Client receives a callback from the user and treats it as the client logging in.
The Client stores the access token and refresh token (if supplied) in the localstorage.
It then passes the access token to requests to the api that it wants to access.  The API checks if the access token is for it and is valid, allows authorisation and completes request.
The API doesn't have any knowledge of refresh tokens.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have now implemented this and learned a bit more.  I keep the refresh token on the server, in a RAM lookup cache.  I keep the access token on the client in a cookie.  All requests are checked for the access token in the cookie, and if stale, the refresh token is used to get a new access token (or login again if refresh token stale).  The client then can visit other actions or pages and has the cookie, but does not expose the refresh token.  Access token is bound to IP address and user agent.  Cookie is HTTPOnly, HTTPS all the things.